# Blazor - how to handle no network connection

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

For me, it is quite surprising the default behaviour of the blazor app when there are network connection problems.  It concerns blazor web components (cshtml pages works differently) when after user will start working with application and network (in most cases Internet) connection will be suspended, pages will be changed at the browser address bar but pages will be not reloaded, pressing buttons will not alert the user that the application doesn't have an internet connection. In the worst scenario, the user will be not aware that the app doesn't have a connection to the server and he can lose some of his work.
How we can handle that and display that there is no internet connection, pls check it and try later.

Comment: be clear about your tags,  blazor-server does not behave this way.

Comment: Believe it or not :) but that is how it works on my computer :). I disconnected the wi-fi and was as I described, a few seconds ago I redo my test and .. still works as I described. And for sure that is blazor-server. Of course, that is true when I use blazor components, cshtml works differently.

Comment: I think we differ about "blazor-server". Can you find the line `services.AddServerSideBlazor();`  in your project?

Comment: of course, that is at startup.cs, ConfigureServices